# how to create a ionic cordova directory? and add local files to that directory am using ionic3 and angular5

Tags: ionic3, angular5

how to create a ionic cordova directory? and add local files to that directory and show that on screen, am using ionic3 and angular5
please help me am searching for the code.

- List item

Comment: Can you calrify your question? Do you need to create a directory and store in it files and list the files inside this directory in app? Is that what you want?

Comment: yes. Now am able to create a directory using externalRootDirectory but how to add files in that directory and how to display it on screen.